# .NET Azure Functions - Model binding

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to automatically bind a model in a parameter in Azure Functions? Similar to how it is done in WebApi controllers? Essentially, when a post body is received, it would be automatically deserialized. And when a query is received, it would also be automatically deserialized. Alternatively, do you have a reliable manual implementation for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the kind of input binding of the function?

Comment: Azure want a json body. So you can create on client a class and then get the json by using a json serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps. Alternatively, add header deserialization.

Query - Get

```
public T AsQueryResult<T>(FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    var queryParameters = executionContext.BindingContext.BindingData.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Query");

    var queryJson = queryParameters.Value!.ToString();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(queryJson); 
}
```

Body - Post

```
public T AsBodyResult<T>(HttpRequest req)
{
    var body = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

POST in Azure Functions:

```
public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{          
   var messageJson = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   var myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDto>(messageJson);
   
   //do something   
}
```

GET  in Azure Functions:

```
public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
   // BODY          
   var messageJson = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   var myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDto>(messageJson);
   
   // QUERY - assuming you are sending json as a query parameter
   string queryJson = req.Query["myQuery"];
   var myModel2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDto>(queryJson);
   //do something   
}
```

NOTE: If you need to send body in a GET request there is something wrong with the logic. In HTTP, GET method is specifically defined to not to include a request body.

Comment: Thank you. But this is only for post. I would like have for get too. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using .net 6

Use [Frombody] in your Azure Functions like this:

```
[FunctionName("QueryData")]
public object QueryData(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST", Route = "data")] HttpRequest request,
    [FromBody] object content) // <---- Put your Object that you like to bind here
{
    // ...
}
```

This [Frombody] is not supported anymore in .NET6 core so you need to install this workaround Library https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureFunctions.MvcModelBinding
which will make it work.

Here is the GitHub Repo with a tutorial how to set this up in your Project:
https://github.com/nazar-kuzo/azure-functions

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.